# LDAP - Get one property of entry

Tags: database, ldap, client

I want to query an ldap server, to only get one property of all entries.

In SQL you could get the same doing: `SELECT property FROM xyz`

I need all `uid` that I can get with the base DN, but only those, for optimisation of data.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP you can specify the attributes you want to retrieve.
So if you set the search attributes to be "uid", for each entry, you will get its DN and its "uid" attribute. There is the only way to optimize the amount of data transfered.

Comment: Hi, I don't understant what you mean by setting the search attributes. My base looks like "ou=people,dc=gi,dc=utc" and I need to get all entries of LDAP, but only uid of them. I don't want any names, phone numbers... etc.. thanks!

Comment: RFC 4511 (LDAP Protocol) defines the search request as such :  
The Search request is defined as follows:  
    SearchRequest ::= [APPLICATION 3] SEQUENCE {  
         baseObject      LDAPDN,  
         scope           ENUMERATED { ... },  
         derefAliases    ENUMERATED {...},  
         sizeLimit       INTEGER (0 ..  maxInt),  
         timeLimit       INTEGER (0 ..  maxInt),  
         typesOnly       BOOLEAN,  
         filter          Filter,  
         attributes      AttributeSelection }  
attributes is where you can chose the attributes returned.